# Changes in $http data from 1 controller to affect another in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

So if my data is coming from a json $http, how do i make it so that if i click vote on one controller, it will sort the order by votes on another controller?

What I have so far isnt working correctly and it seems like the shared data does catches any changes between controller... take it look

```
app.controller('voteController', function ($scope, musicData) {

    musicData.getMusic().then(function(data){
        $scope.music = data.data;
    });


    $scope.upVote = function(music) {

        music.likes++;

    };

    $scope.downVote = function(music) {

        music.dislikes--;

    };

});

// controller for top 5 charts
app.controller('topFiveController', function ($scope, musicData) {

    musicData.getMusic().then(function(data){
        $scope.music = data.data;
    });

    $scope.sortorder = '-likes';


});

// factory to share data between controllers
app.factory('musicData', function($http) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.getMusic = function() {
        return $http.get('app/data/music.json');
    };


    return factory;
});
```

and this is what I have in the mark up

```
<div id="topMusic" ng-controller="topFiveController" ng-model="sortorder">
                    <h3 class="title"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i> Top 5 titles</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="music in music.music | orderBy:sortorder | limitTo: 5">
                          {{music.artist}} - "{{music.title}}"
                        </li>
                    </ul>
</div>


<div id="voteMusic" ng-controller="voteController">
  <h1>Vote here</h1>
  <ul>
                <li class="likeMe" ng-click="upVote(music)">
                <i class= "fa fa-thumbs-up" ></i> like - {{music.likes}}</li>
                <li class="dislikeMe" ng-click="downVote(musics)">
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>dislikes -  
                {{music.dislikes}}</li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

this is how the json file looks like

```
{"music": [
    {
        "artist": "Artst 1",
        "title": "title one",
        "likes": 10,
        "dislikes": 1
    },
    {
        "artist": "Artst 2",
        "title": "title 2",
        "likes": 5,
        "dislikes": 1
    },
    {
        "artist": "Artst 3",
        "title": "title 3",
        "likes": 3,
        "dislikes": 1
    },
    {
        "artist": "Artst 4",
        "title": "title 4",
        "likes": 2,
        "dislikes": 1
    },
    {
        "artist": "Artst 5",
        "title": "title 5",
        "likes": 1,
        "dislikes": 1
    }
]
}
```

Comment: We'd need to see your musicData service to understand how it works.  The easy way would be to put a `$watch` on `music.getMusic()` inside your `topFiveController`, but that might have performance implications on your app.

Comment: thanks! I just edited my post and added how the json object is setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you will actually need to use $rootScope.$broadcast instead of $scope.$emit, as sma suggested.  As you have your markup, voteController is not actually a child of topFiveController.  In your voteController, you will need to inject $rootScope as a dependency, and then use:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('vote');
```

and in topFiveController:

```
$scope.$on('vote', function () {
    // sort
});
```

If you want to update the music object in topFiveController to show the new vote without having to get from the music service again, you can also do this in your voteController:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('vote', $scope.music);
```

then do this in your topFiveController:

```
$scope.$on('vote', function(music) {
    $scope.music = music;
    // sort
});
```

Comment: The way that it's currently set up, you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tvg6h0py/1/ . However, I just noticed that it's kind of weird how you have it structured.  Do you actually have the voting section nested in the ng-repeat for each track?  Is the vote controller correctly adding likes/dislikes to tracks at the moment, even if its not updating the top five view?

Comment: Hey tweb, you can actually avoid having to use emit or broadcast by just nesting your voting div within the ng-repeat.  You can demo it here on plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/4de2DwGyqQMrdLEnLAHI?p=preview  .  I made a couple of changes to your semantics, though.  I changed your ng-repeat to say "song in music" instead of "music in music.music." To do that, I pass data.data.music directly to $scope.music instead of data.data in the topFiveController.  I also changed your upvote and downvote functions in voteController to use song instead of music for clarity.  You can switch them back if you want

Answer (score 1):

You can emit an event from your voteController:

```
$scope.$emit("vote");
```

and then listen for that event in your topFiveController:

```
$scope.$on("vote", function () {
   // sort
});
```

I am using `$emit` because that will send events up the `$scope` inheritance tree.  According to your markup, it looks like voteController is a child scope of topFiveController.  If they are sibling scopes or if the topFiveController is a child scope of voteController, then use `$scope.$broadcast` instead of `$emit`.  `$broadcast` sends events down the inheritance tree.